# MySQL syntax error with simple INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql

With this php/mysql query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Follows (User, Following, Type) VALUES ('$_COOKIE[user]', '$genre', 'Genre'")
```

I am getting the syntax error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

I see nothing wrong with this syntax. Does anyone else?

Comment: It depends what the values of those variables are... you should really be escaping them

Comment: Among other concerns, you're missing the ending `)` for `VALUES`

Comment: Seriously?! It's 2011 and we're still using string interpolation for SQL queries?

Comment: Yep, chances are the variables are causing your headache, one of them contains an apostrophe or slash or is empty altogether.

Answer (score 6):

You have a missing parenthesis:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (... , 'Genre'")
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (... , 'Genre')")
                                                  ^
```

You also have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or parameterized queries. Related:

- [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your last bracket in the query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Follows (User, Following, Type) VALUES ('$_COOKIE[user]', '$genre', 'Genre')")
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is that you're not closing your MySQL statement with the corresponding bracket.

Yours:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Follows (User, Following, Type) VALUES ('$_COOKIE[user]', '$genre', 'Genre'");
```

Correct:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Follows (User, Following, Type) VALUES ('$_COOKIE[user]', '$genre', 'Genre')");
```